# Way to store references to a cloudinary asset

Tags: cloudinary

### Introduction

An upload response of Cloudinary contains, according to the [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/api_response_reference), various information that point to the uploaded asset somehow. Mostly, there is `path`, `public_id`, and `version`. It seems it's the following (excuse my pseudo-BNF):

```
path      = "v" version "/" public_id "." format
public_id = (*"/) ALNUM
version   = DIGITS
```

This resolves to the following "runtime example":

```
path      : "v1552733016/foo/uwx0wujz3noatcgwchpw.jpg"
public_id : "foo/uwx0wujz3noatcgwchpw"
version   : "1552733016"
```

Note `foo` is an additional folder which can be many deep.

### Actual question

How is one supposed to store a reference to this asset in their own system, considering not to miss anything to be stored but on the other hand have the ability to regain several aspects if needed, like the version for example.

In AWS, there is the "ARN" in the style of "URN". Those are colon-separated, namespaced resource identifiers. I love storing these ARNs in my system because their pattern is published and documented.

Unless someone comes up with a better one I guess I store the `path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields needed to completely identify a specific resource are:

- cloud_name (account name, relevant if you have multiple accounts)
- type (how the image was stored, the most options being ('upload','authenticated','private','fetch')
- resource_type (image/video/raw)
- public_id (effectively a 'filename'), which includes the folder path
- version

What you store will depend on your exact requirements.
For example, If all your assets are resource_type: 'image' and type 'upload', which is the most common, you can assume that and hardcode those values.
If you don't use versioning of your assets, you can skip that part, etc.

For building image delivery URLs using the Cloudinary SDK, all you strictly need is the public_id (including path) and the cloud name. Everything else, including any transformations you use for specific usages of the image, is dependent on your requirements